# Postgis: function st_contains does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am struggling to get a simple Postgresql/Postgis statement to work, I need all points within a polygon (in this case a rectangle)

```
SELECT * FROM points_table WHERE ST_Contains( ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((51.8121, 0.13712199999997665, 51.9078, 0.21444399999995767))'), points_table.geom)
```

The error reads

```
ERROR:  function st_contains(geometry, geography) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM points_table WHERE ST_Contains( ST_GEOMFRO...
                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function st_contains(geometry, geography) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 38
```

The answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298611/how-to-find-all-points-within-polygon-in-postgis) amongst others suggests my statement is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you are comparing GEOMETRY and GEOGRAPHY

As in your message error   `st_contains(geometry, geography)`

be sure that your column points_table.geom is a valid GEOMETRY data type and not  a GEOGRAPHY data type  .. for this chek also for the SR you are using  and eventually convert you geomtext as  a valid SR for geography

eg assuming you using as SR 4326

```
SELECT * 
FROM points_table 
WHERE ST_Contains(
  ST_Transform(
  ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((51.8121, 0.13712199999997665, 51.9078, 0.21444399999995767))')
  ,4326)
, points_table.geom)
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by joining on `public.ST_CONTAINS(geom, coords)` instead of `ST_CONTAINS(geom, coords)`

I don't really understand enough about Postgresql to know why this worked though.  I just skimmed https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132103/postgis-st-within-does-not-exist and hoped for the best.

Answer (score 1):

Although I accepted an answer that solved my statement, I feel it important to share an alternative to the explicit scenario (points within a boundary) as this is something I have struggled to find a solution to elsewhere.

`SELECT * FROM points WHERE points.geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(0.13712199999997665, 51.8121, 0.26340800000002673, 51.9135, 4326)`

This one is far simpler and yields the results exactly as required, same as the accepted answer.